# Adding new row on a table tbody by cloning the last row with events attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm trying to clone the last row of a table with input fields that might have events attached, (in this case it's the keyup event). I also change the id's of the input fields to reflect the row where they are, something like:

table[0].field1,table[0].field2...table[1].field1...etc.

The problem is that I can add a row and it gets the events too, and when i write on the new cloned inputs they do start the events. But only on the first row created. If i create a new one, it will render the row with the inputs correctly but not the events. Here's the method:

```
addRow= function(tableid){

    //jquery selector get table tbody with id 
    var table=jQuery('table[id="'+tableid+'"] >tbody');


    //get last row containing input fields with tr class hoverTransparente      
    var lastRow=jQuery('table[id="'+tableid+'"] > tbody > tr:last');

    //make a clone of the row
    var clones = lastRow.clone(true); // copy events/children too

    //get the input fields from the cloned row
    var clonedInPuts=clones.find('input');

    //for each input
    jQuery(clonedInPuts).each(function (){

        //set new input val to empty
        jQuery(this).val("");
        var inputId=jQuery(this).attr('id');

        //table id
        var table=inputId.split("[")[0];
        //column id
        var tableField=inputId.split(".")[1];

        var idnumber=inputId.indexOf("[")+1;

        //convert to number to make addition for new id index
        var number = Number(inputId.charAt(idnumber))+1;
        //replace id index with incrementaed value
        var newId=inputId.replace(inputId.charAt(idnumber),number);

        //change id for new one
        jQuery(this).attr('id',newId);

        //check if this variable exists/is not undefined
        if(window["elements_"+table+"_"+tableField]){
            window["elements_"+table+"_"+tableField].push(jQuery(this).get(0));
        }
    });

    clones.appendTo(table);


}
```

Any ideas? when i try to debug in chrome the event onkeyup from the domtree of the input element is null but if i select using jquery directly and get the .data('events') method it does return an array with the events attached to the input field. Shouldn't the onkeyup return something different from null?

Comment: How do you attach the keyup event to the table row?

Comment: What do you mean? only the input fields have keyup events.jquery .clone() method supposedly copies the events too if you set to true the parameter "withDataAndEvents".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is not on this side but on the original method that creates the events in the original inputs of the existing rows. You need to do this:

```
var selectorStr='input[id^='+table+']&[id$='+tableField+']';
jQuery(document).on('keyup',selectorStr,function(event) {...})
```

instead of:

```
var elements=jQuery('input[id^='+table+']&[id$='+tableField+']');

elements.each(function() {

jQuery(this).keyup(function(){...})
});
```

This will solve the problem of adding new rows to the tablet and the input events actually search for newly added inputs.